# Socket checksum issue

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, checksum

This may be a straightforward solution but basically I am sending a binary file piece-by-piece to another program using TCP and checking to make sure the checksum matches for validity. The problem is the checksum received is never the checksum sent apart from the last part submitted (the remainder).

The code fragment for the sender is:

```
void* buffer = (void *)malloc(BLOCKSIZE+1);
if (!buffer)
  error("Error: malloc error for buffer.\n");
fread(buffer, BLOCKSIZE, 1, fp_read);  //read from binary file for the current block.
int checksum = checksum(buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
n = write(sockfd,buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
if (n < 0)
  error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

For the receiver is is:

```
void* buffer = (void *)malloc(BLOCKSIZE+1);
if (!buffer)
  error("Error: malloc error for buffer.\n");
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
if (n < 0)
  error("Error: reading from socket.");
int checksum = checksumv(buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
```

Anyone see anything wrong with it? The only part having checksums match is the final piece which doesn't completely fill the buffer.

Thanks.

The whole code for the sender is:

```
FILE* fp_read = fopen("file.jpg", "rb");
if (fp_read == NULL)
  error("Cannot open the file for peer piece download.");

fseek(fp_read, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long fileLen = ftell(fp_read);
fseek(fp_read, 0, SEEK_SET);

int checksum, loops = fileLen / BLOCKSIZE;
int remainder = fileLen % BLOCKSIZE;
int segment_num = loops+1;

void* buffer4 = (void *)malloc(BLOCKSIZE+1);
    if (!buffer4)
      error("Error: malloc error for buffer.\n");

    int i, sent = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=loops; i++)
    {
      fread(buffer4, BLOCKSIZE, 1, fp_read);
      checksum = checksumv(buffer4,BLOCKSIZE);

      n = write(sock,buffer4,BLOCKSIZE);
      if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
    if (remainder > 0)
    {
      //Allocate memory
      void* buffer5 = (void *)malloc(remainder+1);
      if (!buffer5)
        error("Error: malloc error for buffer2.\n");

      fread(buffer5, remainder, 1, fp_read);
      checksum = checksumv(buffer5,remainder);

      n = write(sock,buffer5,remainder);
      if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
```

Comment: `write(sockfd,buffer,BLOCKSIZE+1);` Why are you telling `write` to write `BLOCKSIZE + 1` bytes if you have read only `BLOCKSIZE` bytes? (and you didn't even check the return value!)

Comment: I did check the return value with the n variable. Also, changing it to write(sockfd,buffer,BLOCKSIZE); still has the checksum mismatch issue. I was just messing with different things.

Comment: I meant the return value of the `fread`. By the way, `int checksum = checksum(buffer,BLOCKSIZE);` shouldn't compile, the newly declared variable's name shadows the function name.

Comment: Although bad coding design, fread does indeed read the data I want (as checked with print statements.) The actual checksum function name is checksumv(), which does compile.

Comment: "The number of bytes written may be less than  count" <- you should check how many bytes `write` actually wrote, and if it wrote less than `BLOCKSIZE`, try to send the rest, until all has been sent (or the connection died). I don't see you send the checksum, where do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading data:

```
n = read(sockfd,buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
if (n < 0)
  error("Error: reading from socket.");
int checksum = checksumv(buffer,BLOCKSIZE);
```

you need to respect the number of bytes that `read()` says it placed into `buffer` - it may read fewer than `BLOCKSIZE` number of bytes before returning.

Also, I don't see where the checksum is sent (or received) - I only see the file data being sent.  How are you comparing checksums?

Finally, since TCP is a streaming protocol, you'll need to have some way to indicate to receiver when the file data is finished such as by sending the size ahead of the file data, or having some 'out of band' indication.

Answer (score 0):

You're not accumulating your checksum correctly, but you don't need all this complexity just to copy a file:

```
byte buffer[8192];
while ((count = fread(buffer, sizeof buffer, 1, fp)) > 0)
{
    n = write(sock,buffer4,count);
    if (n < 0)
      error("ERROR writing to socket");
    checksum += checksumv(buffer, count); // or possibly ^=, it depends how your checksum is supposed to accumulate
}
```